# Phalcon ORM - integer field id is string after save

Tags: php, types, orm, save, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon for my current project and i'm seeing some strange behaviour with the type casting.

I have this model

```
class Customer extends Model {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
}
```

In my service, i save a new `Customer` model like this:

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->name = 'test';
$customer->save();
var_dump($customer->id);
```

The problem i'm facing is that the `id` is a string, instead of an `integer`. In `db` the fiend of course is an auto increment int, primary key.

Also, I have already added those lines in my db connection

```
\Pdo::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
\Pdo::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
\Pdo::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
```

which only solves the problem when you fetch from database and not when you save.

I don't want to use a getter for id, since I have implemented another functionality with magic setters/getters.

Any solution on this issue?

Comment: What is it look like if you go with `var_dump($customer)`?

Comment: The id is a string when i var_dump the $customer

Comment: Strange. Double checked DB field is an integer?

Comment: Yeah, it's a known issue as you can see here also: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/11091 but still there is no solution for me

Comment: I just was reading [this one](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1434). Seems PDO is functioning that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct issue for this problem is https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/13002 and has been resolved now.
Just use

```
Model::setup([ 'castLastInsertIdToInt' => TRUE ]);
```

in your bootstrapping to activate workaround globally

Comment: You can also use `ini_set('phalcon.orm.cast_last_insert_id_to_int', 'on');` (or set this in your php.ini file of course) - tested in Phalcon 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you trying to define `protected $name` property outside object scope.

You should either make property `$name` public or use setter like `$customer->setName('test');`

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon Model provides function like `beforeSave` and `afterFetch` you can use to cast the id to integer.